# Maximum likelihood estimator when $\sum_{j} \theta_j = 1$. How to impose this condition?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, likelihood, restrictions

I have a sample $x_1,\dots,x_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim}f(;\boldsymbol{\theta})$, where $\boldsymbol{\theta} = (\theta_1,\dots,\theta_d)$, and

1. , $0<\theta_j<1$,
2. $\sum_{j=1}^d\theta_j = 1$.

I can easily implement and evaluate the log likelihood function

$$\ell(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log f(x_i;\boldsymbol{\theta}),$$

however I do not know how to impose the condition

$$\sum_{j=1}^d\theta_j = 1.$$

How is this kind of optimization done in maximum likelihood estimation?

Comment: @Xi'an which reparametrization are you suggesting in order to comply with both conditions?  $\sum_{j=1}^d\theta_j = 1$ implies $\sum_{j=1}^{d-1}\theta_j = \theta_d$, but imposing $0<\theta_j<1$ in the implementation does not seem to be that simple. In theory, it is of course trivial, but my question is more on the practical side.

Comment: @Xi'an The model $f$ contains the vector parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, by formulation, the entries of this parameter are restricted on $(0,1)$ and their sum adds up to $1$. So, I was wondering how to use, for instance, `optim` to maximize my log likelihood function. The restrictions make sense in my model and they are not artificially introduced, as the model is a sort of mixture.

Comment: Define the likelihood to be null outside the parameter space $(0,1)^{d-1}$ and run an optimisation package with no constraint.

Comment: @Xi'an Interesting suggestion. Thanks, I will give it a try. I guess I also need to impose the condition that the sum of the $d-1$ parameters is $<1$, as having $d-1$ parameters in $(0,1)^{d-1}$ does not guarantee that both conditions hold. I was hoping to avoid this sort of additional restrictions, as they tend to make the estimation less efficient in my experience, but I guess there is no way to make the estimation easy.

Answer (score 3):

You can write it as a sum over every $\theta_i$ except the last one, and replace that term with $1 - \sum_{j=1}^{d-1}\theta_i$.

If you also have boundaries (added, see comment), then you are in the realm of nonlinear contrained optimization, for which numerical and analytical approaches exist. Choices will depend on the actual $f$. There is  also the Lagrangian dual theorem which may be important in some cases. Perhaps you can look up a package in $R$ or $Python$ for maximum likelihood estimation and see how they do it.

Comment: Indeed, this is implicit in the condition. However, this cannot be directly implemented as $0< \theta_j <1 $. Sorry I missed mentioning this.

Answer (score 2):

Another practical solution that is pretty popular, is to define $\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and then use some function to transform it to desired range, e.g. in your case, you could use [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)

$$
\ell(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log f\Big(x_i;\;\operatorname{softmax}(\boldsymbol{\theta})\Big)
$$

If you need the parameter to be non-negative, you could use $\exp$ function, etc. The idea is to have unrestricted parameter values, that are transformed using a deterministic function to desired range.